Why does not Shannon Chain Rule work in Quantum Mechanics
Shannon Entropy conditional variant is $H(A|B)=H(AB)-H(B)$. Its chain rule implies: $H(A|BC)=H(AB|C)-H(B|C)$. The Quantum conditional min entropy does not satisfy the chain rule, but satisfies the following in-equation (known as partial chain rule): $$H_{\rm min} (A|BC)\geq H_{\rm min} (AB|C)-\log |B|$$
Why the quantum does not satisfy the Shannon's chain rule?

The von Neumann entropy is the quantum analogue of the Shannon entropy and this entropy does satisfy the chain rule you mention. The quantum min entropy is a quantum analogue of the classical min entropy. But the classical min entropy also does not satisfy that chain rule, so there is no reason why the quantum one should.
